# Find total number of unique elements in two columns combined

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe names_df with 800 million rows with two columns. firstname and lastname. I need to find the total number of unique names from the two columns combined.

```
           first_name last_name
0          john       doe
1          jane       doe
2          doe        john
3          doe        jane
:
799999999  Levi       Ackerman
800000000  Gojo       Satoru
```

I can simply do:

```
unique_names = np.concatenate((names_df.first_name.unique(), names_df.last_name.unique()), axis=None)
unique_names=set(unique_names.tolist())
print(len(unique_names))
```

However, this takes a lot of time and is inefficient, what is a more efficient of finding the total number of unique values from the two columns combined?
the unique_names would look like this =

```
>>>print(unique_names)
>>> {'john','jane','doe','levi','ackerman','Gojo','satoru'}
```

Answer (score 1):

use this(This is faster than your method):

```
set(names_df['first_name'].unique().tolist()+names_df['last_name'].unique().tolist())
```

Comment: i believe my question was not clear, I made some edits to show how the results looks like. Thank you

Comment: Updated my answer kindly have a look

Answer (score 0):

**Edit upon edited question**
If you want all unique values from multiple columns you can use:

```
names= names_df[["first_name", "last_name"]].values.ravel()
unique_names =  pd.unique(names)
n_unique_names = len(n_unique_names)
```

[Please see here](https://www.kite.com/python/answers/how-to-find-the-unique-values-in-multiple-columns-of-a-pandas-dataframe-in-python)

---

Old answer:

You could use [drop_duplicates()](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html) from pandas and then look at the shape of the returned pandas.DataFrame. If / How much faster is to be seen though.

Comment: i believe my question was not clear, I made some edits to show how the results looks like. Thank you

Comment: Updated my answer kindly have a look

Answer (score 0):

IF you have a multicore machine then, sort the data and divide it into 26 batches use python **multiprocessing library**. Get the unique from each batch and then you can merge all those unique df.

Comment: i believe my question was not clear, I made some edits to show how the results looks like. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Creating a temporary third column and computing the length of its unique values should be less computationally expensive.

```
names_df['full_name'] = names_df.first_name + names_df.last_name
total_unique_length = len(names_df.full_name.unique())
names_df = names_df.drop(columns='full_name')
print(total_unique_length)
```

EDIT - based on your edit, you just want unique names from both lists. If there is a Jane Doe and a John Doe, you want [John, Jane, Doe]

In this case it's much easier.

```
total_unique_length = len(names_df.first_name.unique()) + len(names_df.last_name.unique())
print(total_unique_length)
```

Comment: thank you for your response. however len(names_df.first_name.unique()) + len(names_df.last_name.unique()) wouldn't work as both first name can last name can have common entries. example: john doe and doe john your code will give 4 where as the actual results is {john, doe} which is 2